# Exim4: Cannot connect LDAP server with "ldap_require_cert = hard"

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ldap, exim

I'm trying to configure secure connection between `exim` and `slapd` using self-signed certificate.
The `ldap_require_cert = hard` needs for verifying a TLS certificate presented by an LDAP server, but verifying fails on client's authentication:

```
2017-07-20 15:51:26 login authenticator failed for (client) [10.0.5.2]: 435 Unable to authenticate at present (set_id=user1): lookup of "user=uid=user1,ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local pass=123 ldap:///uid=user1,ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local?uid?sub?(&(uid=user1)(objectClass=VirtualMailAccount)(accountActive=TRUE))" gave DEFER: failed to initiate TLS processing on an LDAP session to server mail.domain.local:389 - ldap_start_tls_s() returned -1: Can't contact LDAP server
```

Everything works *fine* with `ldap_require_cert = never`, but I need to verify a server certificate.

Here is a piece of exim configuration file:

```
...
ldap_default_servers = mail.domain.local
ldap_start_tls = true
ldap_require_cert = hard
ldap_version = 3
ldap_ca_cert_file = /etc/exim4/ssl/ldap_ca.cert
...
```

I'm pretty sure that it is not a permission problem (I have set `777` mode during investigation).

Also I was succeed with the same configuration for dovecot, everything works great. Here is a piece of `dovecot-ldap.conf`:

```
...
tls = yes
tls_ca_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/ssl/ldap_ca.cert
tls_require_cert = hard
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `hard` to `demand` solves the problem.
From `man ldap.conf`: `demand | hard  These keywords are equivalent.`